# Passing environment variables to systemd service

Tags: server, systemd, environment-variables

I am trying to start phoenix framework using systemd but the problem is phoenix app is not getting environment variables. Below is my system service

```
[Unit]
Description=Runner for Application
After=network.target # Ensures network is up

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/app
EnvironmentFile=/home/user/app.env
ExecStart=/home/user/app/bin/app start
ExecStop=/home/user/app/bin/app stop
User=user
Restart=on-failure
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

environment file

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/user/app
export PORT=4000
```

How to pass all variables from environment file to service

Comment: AFAIK the systemd EnvironmentFile is just a text file containing `VAR=value` pairs (like the `/etc/environment` file) - not a script

Comment: Make those entries in the environmental file `HOME=/home/user/app` and `PORT=4000` and try again